# vertically misaligned CSS columns with mixed text structure

Tags: html, css, alignment, multiple-columns, vertical-alignment

I'm generating html code which is supposed to be put on a two columns `div`:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
    .legendext{ column-count:2; column-gap:10pt; text-indent:0.0cm; margin-left:1.0cm; margin-right:1.0cm;}
    </style>
    <body>
    <figure>
    <div class="legendext">
    <dl>
    <dt><span>Definition 1</span></dt>
    <dd>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt><span>Definition 2</span></dt>
    <dd>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </dd>
    <dt><span>Definition 3</span></dt>
    <dd>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </dd>
    </dl>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
    </div>
    <figcaption>Figure : My figure.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </head>
```

For an incomprehensible reason, my columns are not correctly vertically aligned (balanced) like this:

[image]

I had a look on this topic [Vertically Misaligned CSS Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415382/vertically-misaligned-css-columns) and tried to modify my code according to the answer but It doesn't give me the expected result:

[image]

The list in two columns is correctly balanced but the rest of my text is not showed in two columns.

This answer is supposed to work with a single ordered list and not with a mixed structure of html tags like in my code.

**Does anyone know what is wrong with my code and how to make my columns correctly balanced ?**

Comment: margin:0 on dl element?

Comment: It could be a solution but if I have several list successively ? How do I set a margin between them ?

Comment: `dl:first-child {margin-top: 0}`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
        margin: 0px;
    }
.legendext
{ 
    column-count:2; 
    column-gap:10pt; 
    text-indent:0.0cm; 
    margin: 5rem;
    }
    .legendext dd {
        margin: 2.5rem 0rem;
    }


    p {
        margin: .5rem 0rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<figure>
<div class="legendext">
<dl>
<dt><span>Definition 1</span></dt>
<dd>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
<ul>
<li>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</li>
<li>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</li>
<li>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
<dt><span>Definition 2</span></dt>
<dd>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</dd>
<dt><span>Definition 3</span></dt>
<dd>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</dd>
</dl>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dolor eu velit dignissim vulputate.</span></p>
</div>
<figcaption>Figure : My figure.</figcaption>
</figure>

</body>

</html>
```